# Change in behaviour for IActionInvokerProviders when using UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute between core 3.1 and dotnet 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, .net-6.0

Context:

Upgrading an existing aspnet application from core 3.1 to dotnet 6.0.

Issue:
We have registered a IActionInvokerProvider in our web app. This simply adds some information to the context route data.
We also use UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute

`app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/somecontroller", "?statusCode={0}");`

According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.iactioninvoker?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> An IActionInvoker is created for each request the MVC handles by querying the set of IActionInvokerProvider instances. See IActionInvokerProvider for more information.

When running this in netcoreapp3.1 when we return a NotFound() I can observe that 2 calls are made to our action provider OnProvidersExecuting. One for the request to the resource and one for a call expected UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute to /somecontroller.

When targeting net6.0 and changing no other code this second call to /somecontroller does not get called only the first . If I call the endpoint /somecontroller?statusCode=404 I it does trigger the invoker. I cannot find a reference to a breaking change anywhere. perhaps I missed it.

Does anyone know what the casue might be?

I have tried altering the ordering of the pipeline.

Tried to repro it in https://github.com/csi-lund/core31tonet6issue
In the version the Action provider never gets called at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a missed breaking change and documentation.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45589

> We skip the IActionInvoker by default as an optimization for
> controllers and pages. This is a really heavyweight way to add route
> data to the pipeline. You can set EnableActionInvokers to true to
> enable this behavior.
>
> builder.Services.AddControllers(o => {
> o.EnableActionInvokers = true; }); In your sample it would be AddMvc (since you're using that).
>
> No change in behaviour without documentation to indicate. (There might
> be might have missed it)
>
> Yes, it seems like we missed this one. I'll make sure it gets
> documented.
>
> PR: #27773 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/27773